# How to print out each index in a 2D list without brackets and empty lines between the index?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:

```
menu=[['1.PEPPERONI $ ' , 8.50],
['2.SIMPLY CHEESE $ ' , 8.50],
['3.GARLIC CHEESE $ ' , 8.50],
['4.HAM & CHEESE $ ' , 8.50],
['5.VEG TRIO ' ,  8.50],
['6.BEEF & ONION $ ' , 8.50],
['7.HAWAIIAN $ ' , 8.50],
['8.APRICOT CHICKEN $ ' , 13.50],
['9.MEATLOVERS $ ' , 13.50],
['10.PERI-PERI CHICKEN $ ' , 13.50],
['11.PHILLY STEAK AND CHEESE $ ' , 13.50],
['12.CHICKEN & CRANBERRY $ ' , 13.50]]
print(menu)
```

When printed out, the menu will include brackets and the menu looks hard to read. Is there any way to print out menu without brackets and each pizza with its price will be on 1 same line. The next pizza and its price will be on the next line below. They should be all vertically aligned and text-based. In short, the printed menu should look easy to read and the price can be seen easily like a real menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list and print the pizza along with its price to make it look nicer.

```
for item in menu:
    print(f"{item[0]}, Price: {item[1]}")
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want some more "alignment" than in the other answer you could try something like the following:

```
import re

menu = ...

re_pizza = re.compile(r'^(\d+\.)([^$]+)')
max_length = max(len(choice.split('.')[1]) for choice, _ in menu) - 1
new_menue = ''
for choice, price in menu:
    no = re_pizza.search(choice).group(1)
    choice = re_pizza.search(choice).group(2).strip()
    new_menue += (no.ljust(4)
                  + choice.ljust(max_length)
                  + f'{price:.2f}$\n'.rjust(7))

print(new_menue)
```

This can be refined. But it would be good if the input menu would be completely regular (in the entry for VEG TRIO the $ is missing).